# Nonlinear model fit for a complex function of two variables?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit the real and imaginary part of the Lorentzian, using MultiNonlinearModelfit function, I am having two independent variables in the problem (x and w, please see the code below), I am not sure how to go about the two independent variables, Here is my data [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmYM_9lNsudPlF6caxsGT9DkDuf3Vvyw/view?usp=sharing)

```
Data = Import["E:\\Shelender\\codes\\Mathematica\\Aelastic \
relaxation\\try.csv"];
real = Data[[All, {1, 2}]];
imag = Data[[All, {1, 3}]];
w = Data[[All, {4}]];
Model = (A*E^(d/x)*tw)/(-I + E^(d/x)*tw);
fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
Rationalize[{real, imag}, 0], ComplexExpand[ReIm@Model], 
Rationalize[{{A, 1.0*10^-4}, {t, 1.0*10^-12}, {d, 10}}, 0], {x}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 10];
fit["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this?

```
real = Data[[All, {1, 4, 2}]];
imag = Data[[All, {1, 4, 3}]];
Model = (A*E^(d/x)*t*w)/(-I + E^(d/x)*t*w);
fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
  Rationalize[{real, imag}, 0],
  ComplexExpand[ReIm @ Model],
  Rationalize[{{A, 1.0*10^-4}, {t, 1.0*10^-12}, {d, 10}}, 0],
  {x, w},
  WorkingPrecision -> 30,
  MaxIterations -> 1000
]
```

The `w` variable doesn't change a whole lot, so it doesn't seem to impact the fit all that much.

## Edit

You can plot the fit for example like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListPlot[{real[[All, {1, 3}]], imag[[All, {1, 3}]]}],
  Quiet @ Plot[
    {fit[1, x, w], fit[2, x, w]}, {x, 0, 1.5597}, 
    PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ],
 {w, 1.255 10^8, 1.256*10^8}
]
```

As you can see, the value of `w` really doesn't influence the fit much.

Comment: @Sjored Smit for plotting I defined two more variables as real1 = Data[[All, {1, 2}]];
imag1 = Data[[All, {1, 3}]]; and tried plotting using how[ListPlot[{real1, imag1}], 
 Plot[{fit[1, x], fit[2, x]}, {x, 0, 
   Max[real1[[All, 1]], imag1[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All], 
 PlotRange -> All] but I think the problem is with fit[1,x] and fit[2,x] but could not figure out

Comment: @ShelenderKumar `fit` is a function of `x` and `w`. You can't plot it without giving it values for `w` as well, so you need to call is as `fit[1, x, w]` and `fit[2, x, w]}` (with appropriate values for `x` and `w` of course).

Comment: @Sjored Smit My bad, but I think it is not a good idea to plot like this, because in reality w is not monotonic, but I tried this Plot[{fit[1, x, w], fit[2, x, w]}, {x, 0, 1.5597}, {w, 1.255 10^8,1.256*10^8}, PlotRange -> All] and it gave me error An option must be a rule or a list of rules

Comment: `Plot` is for x-y plots only. Try setting a constant value for `w` instead. I'll update with an example.